# Loop through JSONObject in angular and print only certain values

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

Hi I have JSONObject like below :

```
$scope.controls = {"fields":[{"id":1,"name":"Sales Figures 2017","area":"sales","value":"1800"},{"id":2,"name":"Are you on commission","area":"support","value":"Yes"}]}
```

I am trying to loop and display result like below but only need "name" and "value" values.

Output to be like

1. Sales Figures 2017 : 1800
2. Are you on commission : Yes

Below is what I have done to get only the key and the value but it is not displaying anything.

```
<div ng-repeat="key in controls"> 
   {{key.name}} : {{key.value}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access `fields` in the controls object since that's where the array is.

```
<div ng-repeat="key in controls.fields"> 
   {{key.name}} : {{key.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect it worked.Thanks. Will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

access the `fields` property from `ng-repeat`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.controls = {"fields":[{"id":1,"name":"Sales Figures 2017","area":"sales","value":"1800"},{"id":2,"name":"Are you on commission","area":"support","value":"Yes"}]}


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="key in controls.fields"> 
   {{key.name}} : {{key.value}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for explaining it so well.